# Using Commands to make chests with stuff inside

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every time I try to make a filled chest it is always empty. I am trying to fill it up with raw meat for a restaurant I am doing

```
/give TehFireFace chest{display:{Name:"\"FOOD THAT NEEDS TO BE COOKED\""},BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{Slot:0,id:beef,Count:64},{Slot:1,id:beef,Count:64},{Slot:2,id:beef,Count:64},{Slot:3,id:chicken,Count:64},{Slot:4,id:chicken,Count:64},{Slot:5,id:chicken,Count:64},{Slot:6,id:cod,Count:64},{Slot:7,id:cod,Count:64},{Slot:8,id:cod,Count:64},{Slot:9,id:porkchop,Count:64},{Slot:10,id:porkchop,Count:64},{Slot:11,id:salmon,Count:64},{Slot:12,id:salmon,Count:64}]}} 64
```

Comment: I assume the game in question is Minecraft.  Please add that as a tag.

Comment: sorry that was my fault

Comment: Show us what you tried, otherwise we can't help you (or just direct you to the wiki).

Comment: i put it next to my question

Comment: it doesnt work it says unknown item name

Comment: hey it gives me an empty chest

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of the game you are using, the command may differ.
In my case, I was using Version 1.8.9.

According to a post from Skylinerw on the [minecraft forums](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/redstone-discussion-and/2330571-i-want-to-give-a-player-a-chest-that-when-placed), this is how you give a chest with items:

```
/give [USER] minecraft:chest 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{Slot:0,id:minecraft:stone,Count:1}]}}
```

So for your case it would be:

```
/give TehFireFace minecraft:chest 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{Slot:0,id:minecraft:beef,Count:64},{Slot:1,id:minecraft:beef,Count:64},{Slot:2,id:minecraft:beef,Count:64},{Slot:3,id:minecraft:chicken,Count:64},{Slot:4,id:minecraft:chicken,Count:64},{Slot:5,id:minecraft:chicken,Count:64},{Slot:6,id:minecraft:cod,Count:64},{Slot:7,id:minecraft:cod,Count:64},{Slot:8,id:minecraft:cod,Count:64},{Slot:9,id:minecraft:porkchop,Count:64},{Slot:10,id:minecraft:porkchop,Count:64},{Slot:11,id:minecraft:salmon,Count:64},{Slot:12,id:minecraft:salmon,Count:64}]},display:{Name:"\"FOOD THAT NEEDS TO BE COOKED\""}}
```

Comment: it dosent work it gives me an empty chest

Comment: im using 1.13 so that does not work